# Microsoft Web Platform Installer Error

Tags: installation

It will sound to be stupid. But, today when I was trying to install Microsoft Web Platform Installer 4.6 I am getting the following error message and it doesn't allow be to install the application.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPI 4.5 Error after upgrading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964634/wpi-4-5-error-after-upgrading)

Comment: It looks like a Microsoft server-side error. See here http://stackoverflow.com/q/14964634/325521

Comment: But for me it is almost half an hour. I did uninstalled and rebooted the system twice. But it is still giving me the same error. Any Suggestions Shiva.

Comment: Hi Shiva, After 1 more restart it seems to be working fine. Thnaks.